# Create view showing count of users BETWEEN date AND date

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Using SQL Server

```
select ID, user, DateLogin 
from userLogin
```

```
1 - Dragon  - 25/5/2021
2 - Fllying - 26/7/2021 
2 - Report  - 27/9/2021
```

```
select IDSet, StartSet, EndSet 
from Setting
```

```
1 - 1/5/2021 - 4/6/2021
2 - 1/7/2021 - 4/8/2021
```

I want to create a view showing count of users BETWEEN `StartSet` and `EndSet`.

Example

```
IDSet  countUser  StartSet  EndSet 
------------------------------------
  1       1      1/5/2021 - 4/6/2021
  2       1      1/7/2021 - 4/8/2021
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select IDSet , StartSet ,EndSet, count(*) as countUser
from Seting s
join userLogin ul
on u.DateLogin between s.StartSet and s.EndSet
group by IDSet , StartSet ,EndSet
```